# Enforce distinctness of data by multiple columns combined - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to insert data to a PostgreSQL table distinctly using multiple columns?

for example, if I have a `people` table that looks like that:

| first_name | last_name | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alon | Barad | Broadway st |
| John | Foo | Lambda st |
| Alon | Levy | Broadway st |

I want to insert data to my table and set rules in my database server so that if the `first_name` column and the `address` column are the same, the record will not be inserted.

In my example, record number 3 should not be inserted because it has the same `first_name` and `address` as record number 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique constraint on the two columns:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD UNIQUE (first_name, address);
```

Then use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (first_name, last_name, address)
   VALUES (.....)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```